# Apply mann-kendall analysis on stacked raster in R as a function

Tags: raster, r, regression

I want to run a mann-kendall trend analysis with pre-whitening on a stacked raster and then save the resulting `tau`, `sen-slope` and `p_value`.  I am currently doing this by looping through every pixel but it is incredibly slow so I am wondering if there is a better approach to this? I am using the `modifiedmk` package for the trend assessment. I would be ok with any package that applies pre-whitening, and returns a sen slope, a tau value and a p-value though.

This is my current code:

```
library(Kendall)
library(zyp)
library(gimms)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(modifiedmk)

#create a fake raster
r = raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
r[] = rnorm(n = ncell(r))

#make raster stack
stacked = stack(x = c(r, r*2, r))
stacked2 = stack(x = c(r, r*2, r))
stacked3 = stack(x = c(r, r*2, r))

#get a depth of 9
final_stacked = stack(stacked, stacked2, stacked3)

#some empty data to repopulate
coef = raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
p = raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
t = raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)

#loop through every pixel stack and runb a mann kendall test
for (r in 1:nrow(coef)){
  for (c in 1:ncol(coef)){

    #one pixel stack
    pixel = data.frame(final_stacked[r, c][1,])
    names(pixel) = 'Values'

    #run mann kendall
    result = pwmk(pixel$Values)

    #save the tau, p-value and sen slope
    tau = result[[7]]
    p_value = result[[4]]
    sens = result[[3]]

    #save the value to new rasters
    coef[r,c] = sens
    p[r,c] = p_value
    t[r,c] = tau
  }

}
```

I also tried this which should be faster than looping if it worked:

```
tsfun <- function(x) { 
  if(all(is.na(x))){ 
    return(NaN) 
  } else { 
    r <- data.frame(pwmk(x))
    names(r) = c("Z", "Sen", "Old_Sen", "p", "s", "var(s)", "Tau")
    a <- r$Sen
    return(a) 
  }
} 

raster.mkt <- calc(final_stacked, fun=tsfun, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but it returns:

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function arguments?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check that your function for `calc` works before using it:

```
> tsfun(runif(3))
Error in names(r) = c("Z", "Sen", "Old_Sen", "p", "s", "var(s)", "Tau") : 
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

`calc` tries to trap errors and gives a less informative error message. Running it separately can give an insight.

This error is because you've got a data frame with one column and seven rows and trying to give the column names. You can more easily extract the element you want from the `pwmk` function:

```
 pwmk(runif(3))[["Sen's Slope"]]
```

So rewrite `tsfun` like this:

```
> tsfun = function(x,na.rm){
      if(all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
      return(pwmk(x)[["Sen's Slope"]])
  }
```

and then this works:

```
> raster.mkt <- calc(final_stacked, fun=tsfun, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Problem here might be if you want to get more than just one value out of the `pwmk` function - then you either have to call this several times or try something else. Here's something else:

First make some test data

```
r1 = raster(matrix(runif(24),4,6))
r2 = raster(matrix(runif(24),4,6))
r3 = raster(matrix(runif(24),4,6))
z = stack(r1,r2,r3)
```

Then convert the stack into an array, and apply the `pwmk` function, converting to `vector` because `pwmk` complains about getting a matrix:

```
pw = apply(as.array(z),c(1,2),function(x){pwmk(as.vector(x))})
```

That is now an array with the values from `pwmk` in. Convert to a stack requires a bit of permutation but after trial and error this seems to do it:

```
s = stack(brick(aperm(pw,c(2,3,1))))
```

To test, the `pwmk` value from cell (2,3) is:

```
> pwmk(c(z[2,3,]))
         Z-Value      Sen's Slope old. Sen's Slope          P-value 
       0.0000000       -0.2621047       -0.2515844        1.0000000 
               S           Var(S)              Tau 
      -1.0000000        1.0000000       -1.0000000
```

Which should be element (2,3,) from the stack:

```
> s[2,3,]
     Z.Value Sen.s.Slope old..Sen.s.Slope P.value  S Var.S. Tau
[1,]       0  -0.2621047       -0.2515844       1 -1      1  -1
```

So now you have a stack with 7 layers, one from each of the quantities output by `pwmk`:

```
> s
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 4, 6, 24, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       :    Z.Value, Sen.s.Slope, old..Sen.s.Slope,    P.value,          S,     Var.S.,        Tau 
min values  :  0.0000000,  -0.5586920,       -0.4114719,  1.0000000, -1.0000000,  1.0000000, -1.0000000 
max values  :  0.0000000,   0.5530541,        0.2235587,  1.0000000,  1.0000000,  1.0000000,  1.0000000
```

Then doing `image(s[[2]])` should be a map of "Sen's Slope".